# Bash script variable value changing when running AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have written this script to capture all instances in an AWS region then print out the AZ, VolumeId, InstanceId, and Volume size to a file.  The execution seems smooth until line 13. All the values are received as per expectation. I get the instance_id's required. I have checked the values in `instance_id` variable using a for loop and I have multiple ids. When the script reaches line 14, there is an error saying that there is no instance id. The `echo` command shows the instance ids in the variable but the `describe-instance` command seems to not receive it. 
Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
envs=("aws_cloud" "aws_dev" "aws_prod")
i=0
vols=""
echo "AvailabilityZone  ,   VolumeId    ,   InstanceId  ,   Size">>untagged_volumes.txt
for env in aws_cloud aws_dev aws_prod
    do
    for region in ca-central-1 us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-west-1 eu-central-1 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2
    do
        instance_id=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile=${env} --region=${region} --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key== `Name`].Value) && (Attachments[?State!=""])].{InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId}' --output text ) 
        for instance in "${instance_id}"
        do
            ec2_name=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --profile=${env} --region=${region} --instance-ids=${instance} --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text)

            vol_info=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile=${env} --region=${region} --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=${instance} --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key== `Name`].Value) && (Attachments[?State!=""])].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,AZ:AvailabilityZone,Size:Size}' --output text)
            echo "${env}    ${ec2_name}""${vol_info}">>untagged_volumes.txt
        done
    done
    i=${i+1}
done
```

I am out of my wits trying to debug. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

***Edit:***
So after staring at the error for hours what I understood was that for one instance there was a single id returned and then a string was returned which had that instance id along with single quotes

> An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the
>   DescribeInstance' does not exist instance ID 'i-02f4a---------------

so i checked for any values i get that were greater than the length of instance id. according to aws docs they say that the id length for instances is fixed and that is 17+2 for i and -. After checking for any instance id longer than 19 we can only use the ids with length 19.
Here is the correct code (for anyone who might need it).

```
#!/bin/bash
envs=("aws_cloud" "aws_dev" "aws_prod")
vols=""
echo "Environemnt   ,   InstanceName    ,   AvailabilityZone    ,   VolumeId    ,   InstanceId  ,   Size">>untagged_volumes.txt
for env in aws_cloud aws_dev aws_prod
    do
    for region in ca-central-1 us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-west-1 eu-central-1 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2
    do
        instance_id=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile=${env} --region=${region} --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key== `Name`].Value) && (Attachments[?State!=""])].{InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId}' --output text );
        for j in ${instance_id}
        do
            if [[ "${#j}" -gt 19 ]] || [[ "${#j}" -lt 19 ]]
            then
                continue
            else
                ec2_name=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --profile="${env}" --region="${region}" --instance-ids="${j}" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text)

                vol_info=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --profile=${env} --region=${region} --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values="${j}" --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key== `Name`].Value) && (Attachments[?State!=""])].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,AZ:AvailabilityZone,Size:Size}' --output text)
                echo "${env}    ${ec2_name}     ""${vol_info}">>untagged_volumes.txt
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: why do you need the line ```instance_id=( $instance_id )``` ?

Comment: @NuneIsabekyan nvmind, it was from the initial versions of the script. i'll remove that. but i've checked the error persists.

Comment: `for instance in "${instance_id}"` will only have one pass, because of the quotes. If `${instance_id}` is more than one, remove the quotes.

Comment: Also `set -x` is your friend... Put that at the top and you might find the problem quickly.

Comment: @AronGriffis, i dont get your point regarding quotes. when i checked with quotes the instances returned were 2 and when i checked without quotes the instances returned were 3. please elaborate

Comment: @MuhammadHasan in shell, `for x in STUFF` splits STUFF on whitespace to loop over the values. For example, `for x in 1 2 3` will run the loop three times, assigning `$x` as `1`, `2`, `3` in sequence. But `for x in "1 2 3"` will run the loop only once, assigning `$x` as `1 2 3`. Making sense now?

Comment: Also, have you added `set -x` to the top? If you're "out of your wits trying to debug," that's the first step to understanding what your script is doing when you run it. 

Comment: @AronGriffis, thanks alot. but it seems the last of my wits still prevented me from going into set -x. but i'll look it up. Also, found the problem, just updating with the correct code. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Aplogies everyone for taking you time. And also for posting after so long. The problem was not with the code. The problem was due to the gitbash terminal. As soon as i ran my code in ubuntu terminal the code executed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This piece I belive will help you correct your script

`` instance_id=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes  --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key== `Name`].Value) && (Attachments[?State!=""])].{InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId}' --output text); for i in ${instance_id}; do aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids=${i};done ``